# How to convert MySQL query to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to convert this query to CodeIgniter but I'm just a beginner. I find how can I convert simple SQL but this code is so difficult for me. Is there anyone can help me for convert this code to CodeIgniter?

```
SELECT
    cm.customerID,cm.customerName, cm.phone,adr.address,
    adr.city, adr.zipcode,
    bd.bookingDate,bd.startBooking,
    bd.endBooking, pt.type
FROM
    customers cm, addresses adr, bookings bd, paymentTypes pt,customer_payment cp
WHERE
    cm.customerID=adr.customerID AND
    cm.customerID=bd.customerID AND
    pt.paymentID=cp.paymentID AND
    cm.customerID=cp.customerID
ORDER by
    bookingDate;
```

Comment: I apologise for Marcin's tone (the comment has been reported to moderator). However, we do ask for a minimum amount of research prior to posting questions. Is there a tutorial you can use to see how to make database calls in CodeIgniter?

Comment: This query in any case should not be too hard. Your `WHERE` clauses are all joins - is there a section in the manual for joining tables together?

Comment: I m sorry, I m just beginner in codeigniter. I dont have any tutorial

Comment: Please search for "CodeIgniter query tutorial" or "CodeIgniter database example" in your favourite search engine. I expect the manual would be quite good too - it is a very popular framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple way

`$this->db->query("SELECT cm.customerID,cm.customerName, cm.phone,adr.address, adr.city, adr.zipcode, bd.bookingDate,bd.startBooking, bd.endBooking, pt.type FROM customers cm, addresses adr, bookings bd, paymentTypes pt,customer_payment cp WHERE cm.customerID=adr.customerID AND cm.customerID=bd.customerID AND pt.paymentID=cp.paymentID AND cm.customerID=cp.customerID ORDER by bookingDate");`

Answer (score 0):

Join Query for other way.

`$this->db->SELECT( cm.customerID,cm.customerName, cm.phone,adr.address, adr.city, dr.zipcode, bd.bookingDate,bd.startBooking, bd.endBooking, pt.type);`

`$this->db->FROM(customers cm);`

`$this->db->join(addresses adr, adr.customerID=cm.customerID);`

`$this->db->join(bookings bd, bd.customerID=cm.customerID );`

`$this->db->join(customer_payment cp, cp.customerID=cm.customerID);`

`$this->db->join(paymentTypes pt, pt.paymentID=cp.paymentID);`

`$this->db->order_by("bd.bookingDate","asc");`